# Save program state for otroslogviewer log

Tags: otroslogviewer

How can I save the state of the log viewer for a specifc file, i.e. the activated filters, columns etc.?

I only see an option to save the logging data not my configured "view".

Comment: You could also try [LogMX](http://www.logmx.com) which handles filtering state quick save/load, and columns sorting/sizing quick save. It's also a good and complete log analyzer

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible in current version. There is a 
[issue on OtrosLogViewer site](https://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/issues/detail?id=303&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary%20Component), but there is no plan to implement this.

Comment: Yeah, I'd seen that, I wanted to make sure it's the same for "functional" view settings too. It's really a shame, because I like the viewer very much otherwise.